# Possible undelete of answer?

Tags: support

I was browsing around since I just added TPM to my older motherboard and I wanted to check the full version.  While browsing I stumbled across https://askubuntu.com/a/1415651/231142 where it is deleted.  While they marked it as from SuSE Linux, the answer is exactly the same for Ubuntu.

Running that answer for my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, I get this output.

```
$ cat /sys/class/tpm/tpm0/device/firmware_node/description 
TPM 1.2 Device
```

Which seems very valid to me.

My question then would be do we leave this answer deleted even though it is a valid answer but mentions SuSE Linux?

Comment: My own thought is: make a new answer with your findings. It would be a better answer having been written for and tested on Ubuntu...

Answer (score 2):

I think that answers for other Linux distros should be kept if they seem likely to be relevant for Ubuntu.